# How to check if a word is preceded by a character?

Tags: regex

I have the string `biz'baz`. `biz` can be anything, so something like `bla'baz` would be fine; but I want it returns `bizbaz` if the string becomes `bizbaz`, and returns nothing if `baz` is preceded from `'`. How can I do something with this logic? Do I need a lookahead? `baz` may have more characters after it.

`biz'baz` would return no match.

`bizbaz` would return a match (`bizbaz`).

`bizbiz'baz` would return no match.

`hellohi'bazhello` would return no match.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes, but my tries are completely out of context, so I don't think it was useful to post what I tried.

Comment: What regex flavour are you using? Can you give a clear example of input / output expected ?

Comment: @UlysseBN javascript's flavor. Bytheway, yes. Edited.

Comment: Also If you add context, and the regex (or other stuff) you tried it would **always** be better.

Comment: How about `[^']*baz` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for character negation:

```
/[^']baz/
```

And if you want to match the whole sentence:

```
/.*[^']baz.*/
```

[Check the live example.](https://regex101.com/r/x3MbId/3)

Answer (score 1):

Using a lookahead is a good solution.

You can use:

```
/(?!^\p{L}*'\p{L}*(?:\s|$))(^\p{L}+)/
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/vuEvlN/2/)

In this case, you need to use some form of relevant anchor for the lookahead to make sense. You can use `^` for the start of the line, but some anchor is needed or the word characters after the `'` would be matched.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
\Bbaz
```

The `\B` means "not a word boundary".

A word boundary is where you have an alphanumeric character [A-Za-z0-9] or an underscore (which counts as a letter because of historical reasons), and a letter which isn't any of those things, next to each other.

So:
  biz'baz - no match: there's a "word boundary" beside the b.

bizbaz - match: there's no word boundary by the b.

bizbiz'baz - no match: there's a "word boundary" beside the b.

hellohi'bazhello - no match: there's a "word boundary" beside the b.

biz@baz - no match: there's a "word boundary" beside the b.

biz_baz - match: there's no "word boundary" beside the b, because an underscore is a letter because silly reasons.

If the underscore matters, then you can explicitly list the characters you count as word characters, like so:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+baz
```

That behaves the same, except for two things.

1) It doesn't treat underscores as letters.

2) On a match, it matches the whole word, not just the "baz" part.

Comment: Why should I not match `biz@baz`, or `biz baz`?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You've asked that the preceding character be a word character. @ is not a word character.

Comment: Updated my answer to clarify.